# Pandas - Compare each row with one another across dataframe and list the amount of duplicate values

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to add a column to an existing dataframe that compares every row in the dataframe against each other and list the amount of duplicate values. (I don't want to remove any of the rows, even if they are entirely duplicated with another row)

The duplicates column should show something like this:

```
Name Name1 Name2 Name3 Name4 Duplicates

Mark Doug  Jim   Tom   Alex  5
Mark Doug  Jim   Tom   Peter 4
Mark Jim   Doug  Tom   Alex  5
Josh Jesse Jim   Tom   Alex  3
Adam Cam   Max   Matt  James 0
```

Comment: Could you provide more clarification on what you are trying to do? The column duplicates does not make sense in the output example. pandas does have duplicate functions like `.duplicated`  which will return boolean and you could count those groupby.. and use subsets and first etc.

Comment: shouldn't the first value be `5`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can convert your dataframe to an array of `set`s, then use numpy broadcasting to compare each combination (except the diagonal) and get the max intersection:

```
names = df.agg(set, axis=1)
a = df.agg(set, axis=1).to_numpy()
b = a&a[:,None]
np.fill_diagonal(b, {})
df['Duplicates'] = [max(map(len, x)) for x in b]
```

output:

```
   Name  Name1 Name2 Name3  Name4  Duplicates
0  Mark   Doug   Jim   Tom   Alex           5
1  Mark   Doug   Jim   Tom  Peter           4
2  Mark    Jim  Doug   Tom   Alex           5
3  Josh  Jesse   Jim   Tom   Alex           3
4  Adam    Cam   Max  Matt  James           0
```

Comment: one additional question for you, ideally I would be able to run this on a dataframe with upwards of 50k rows, however I run into speed/memory issues with anything more than around 5-10k. Any ideas on getting around that?

Comment: @baseballdude7711 the thing is that you want to compare each row to all other ones, this is very expensive and the memory consumption increases quadratically (n^2, 10K rows gives ~100M comparisons). There is not much to do if you really want to perform all comparisons. Maybe you can identify subgroups to limit the comparisons?

Answer (score 0):

something you can use is the DataFrame's handy dandy [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) method. This will allow you to group your data(frame) by a specified subset of attributes/columns, *and* use the `size()` or `count()` method to get the number of rows in each group:

```py
# group pandas.DataFrame df by Names 1-4 and summarize with count
duplicates = df.groupby(['name_1','name_2','name_3','name_4']).size().sort_values(ascending=False).reset_index(name='duplicates')
```

Note: I use the `reset_index()` method here to return a DataFrame instead of a Series. I use the `sort_values()` method to order the dataframe by the size (in this case, the number of rows in each group).

Answer (score 0):

This is something I came up with, not an optimal solution - however, works!

```
unique_values_dict={} # dictionary to store the unique values of each column
columns=df.columns # all columns are kept in the columns variable
for c in columns: # for each column, find the distribution and store in a dictionary
    unique_values=[ (i,j) for i,j in df[c].value_counts().items()]
    unique_values_dict[c]=unique_values

df['duplicates']=0 # add a column called 'duplicates' with 0 as the default value


def count_duplicates(row):
'''
 row: Each row of the dataframe
 returns: sum of duplicate items in the row, across the df
'''
    dups=row['duplicates']
    for c in columns:
        #print(c,row[c],unique_values_dict[c][1][0])
        if(row[c]==unique_values_dict[c][1][0]):
            dups+=unique_values_dict[c][1][1]
    #print(dups)       
    return dups
df['duplicates']=df.apply(lambda row:count_duplicates(row),axis=1)
```